# GA Event Tracking for outbound links not working

Tags: html, google-analytics, tracking

I've been trying to capture clicks to Amazon from my site through GA but I don't seem to record anything. The code I use on the a href tag is

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Affiliate', 'Amazon', 'url', 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00C76P7Q2/']);"
```

Here's an example of a page: http://www.thingforyourdesk.com/shop/desk-accessories/house-of-marley-midnight-wireless-bluetooth-portable-audio-system-speaker/ (the link is "View on Amazon")

I have Universal Analytics installed on the site.

Comment: The code you're showing is not universal analytics code, so that's probably why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two problems with your example, you are using the wrong version of the code and the wrong parameters. With Universal Analytics the `_gaq.push()` has been replaced by the `ga send` method. Also it seems like you are trying to pass key/value pairs as parameters ("Affiliate","Amazon") which results in an invalid value for the last parameter (its categor,action,label,value, where value - if present, it is optional - must be an integer).

[Correct syntax looks like that:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
ga('send', 'event', 'evenCategory', 'evenAction', 'eventLabel');
```

Comment: I now have onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'amazon');" but it still doesn't seem to track any clicks. I've defined the goal in GA as well.

Comment: Do you look into the realtime reports ? This will take a bit of time before events show up in the standard reports. And if you use Chrome I recommend you install the GA debugger extension which will tell you if your GA calls are being sent: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en, or give you a halfway decent error message in the browser console if they are not.

Comment: Still nothing, do you mind having a look on the page?

Comment: I still see the old _gaq code on the "view on amazon" button.